# SD card has no partition table and has no file system

Tags: partitioning, mount, filesystem, sd-card

[image]I have a problem reading a sd card which I use on my phone. It has no partition table and file system and I don't know how to make it a legit SD card which I can store my files in. When I open the terminal and use `sudo fdisk -l`, it was like this.

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 29.6 GiB, 31767658496 bytes, 62046208 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 5870CB3F-39B7-B04B-ADF8-A4F386347481
```

Hope someone could help. Thanks.

Comment: Please run `$ gnome-disks &` from the terminal (bash) or `disks` from the dash (Win+a, type 'disks' and click on it). Click on your SD-card and report back (change your post) what it tells about the card.

Comment: Does the card still work with your phone?

Comment: It doesn't work on my phone and it says that it is corrupted.

Comment: @hannu can you see the picture?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This is a community wiki.  Feel free to edit to correct or add information.**

*Warning: Before proceeding, make a backup of any data you may want to keep.*

*Note: You may use other tools to accomplish the same tasks.  I mention `gparted` because it is reliable and easy to use.*

**Background:** Phones and other devices usually use `msdos` partition tables (not `gpt`) with FAT32 or exFAT partitions.  The issue is not necessarily how the partition is *formatted*, but how the drive is *initialized*.

1. Wipe the partition table with `dd`:

   ```
   sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdx bs=1M count=1
   ```

   Change `/dev/sdx` as appropriate to refer to your card.  I intentionally do not put `/dev/sdb` in the command to avoid unintentionally damaging drives by copying and pasting.
2. Run `gparted`.  A message should pop up that says the drive needs to be `initialized` (ie, the partition table need to be created).  Pick the option that says `msdos`.
3. Format the card to `FAT32` using `gparted` (right click and look for appropriate options).  If it does not work, try formatting as `exFAT`.
4. Run `sync` and remove the card.

   *Note: Running `sync` is unnecessary, but I like to run it in situations like this, just in case.*
5. Check to see if the card now works with your phone.  Then check if it works with other devices as intended.

   If the card does not work, you may try formatting with `exFAT` (step 3).  No need to repeat wiping and initialization if the partition table or disk label type is `msdos` or similar, not `gpt`.

Comment: Took me so long to use the command above. Is it normal?

Comment: I hope you weren't trying to recover data off it.  Always make a backup first before toying with it if you want to keep the data.

Comment: Its done and I'm unable to make it with count=1, hahaha. The disk became unallocated now. And I created a partition table using gparted and it is still unallocated. What should I do to make it usable again?

Comment: dd on `/dev/sdx' (with '.../sdb' being the correct one to use) may be very confusing for a person that isn't knowledgeable enough. Please explain to replace /sdx' with what is fit for the situation.

Comment: @xiota please note that `disks` is just fine for formatting too.

Comment: Thanks it worked! Actually it was last time I just didn't tell you guys that its already solved. Anyway thanks!